# Remove X-SA-Exim Headers from out going emails

Tags: email-server, exim, spamassassin, email

I am using EXIM4 on Ubuntu 12.04 with Spamassassin for sending emails. Any emails will be relayed through Amazon SES service. But I want to hide the bellow headers in outgoing emails.

```
X-SA-Exim-Connect-IP: <locally generated>
X-SA-Exim-Mail-From: user@mydomain.com
X-SA-Exim-Scanned: No (on ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.yy-yyyyy-1.compute.internal); SAEximRunCond expanded to false
X-SES-Outgoing: 2014.07.24-54.240.10.16
```

Can any one help how to hide those headers from outgoing emails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the transport(s) that is being used to send the emails outbound, add this:

```
headers_remove = x-sa-exim-connect-ip : x-sa-exim-mail-from : x-sa-exim-scanned
```

You could do this in the routers too if you wanted, assuming that the x-sa-exim-* headers are being added during the ACL's.  If it's not part of your ACL's, Routers, or Transports, then you are using a global system filter and it means you must configure your app which is doing the scanning to not add them in the mail, only log them (or similar)...if you can configure it to do so.